# Google Scripts Custom Object Returning only a String

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to incorporate what should be basic oop into my google script, but the 1 method that I have written for my object is being treated as a string, not a function. Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {  
  var newObj = new MyObject();
  Logger.log(newObj.id)
}

var MyObject = function ( ) {
  this.id = function ( ) {
    // If exists, then get a script property, else solicit it from user
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var myProperty = scriptProperties.getProperty("myProperty");

    if(myProperty == "FALSE" || myProperty == null){
      var newMyProperty = Browser.inputBox('Please enter the property. Then hit ok.',Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }

    // return the newMyProperty, or if cancelled return FALSE or 'null'
    if(newMyProperty == 'cancel'){
      return myProperty;
    }else{
      scriptProperties.setProperty('myProperty', newMyProperty);
      return newMyProperty;
    }
  }
}
```

What ends up being logged in the logger is the full text "function ( ) {
// If exists, then get a script property, else solicit it from....."; instead of actually executing the function. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line in your code:

```
Logger.log(newObj.id)
```

To:

```
Logger.log(newObj.id());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Im a bit embarrassed with the simplicity, and that I couldn't find/figure that out, but I couldn't...so thank you.